# I want to show the different panel when i click the HTML list item

Tags: javascript, dom

my code
by clicking on first i have to show pnl and i have to hide panel1
by clicking on the second i have to do opposite

```
<ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous"  onclick="showPanel('pnl')"><a href="#">Today's Action Items</a> </li>
    <li class="next" onclick="showPanel('Panel1')"><a href="#" >All Pending Action Items</a> </li>
  </ul>
    <script>
        function showPanel(panId)
        {
            var panel = document.getElementById("MainContent_" + panId)
            panel.style.display='block';
        }
 </script>
```

can any body help me on this

Comment: can you use jquery? it's simple..

Comment: $("element").toggle() can help in jquery

Answer (score 1):

Hide one of the panels initially and keep a reference to the panel that is currently shown. When one of the links is clicked you can just access the currently shown panel and hide it.

```
(function() {
   var panel;

   window.showPanel = function(panId) {
       if (panel) { // hide currently shown panel
           panel.style.display = 'none';
       }
       panel = document.getElementById("MainContent_" + panId)
       panel.style.display = 'block';
   };
}());
```

I use the immediate invoke function expression only to avoid defining `panel` in global scope.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6dbfu/)

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xS3kq/)**

you can use a `class` for hiding other **panels**

```
function showPanel(panId)
{
   var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
   for(var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++)
   {
      panels.item(i).style.display='none';
   }
   var panel = document.getElementById("MainContent_" + panId);
   panel.style.display='block';
}
```

html:

```
<div class="panel" id="MainContent_pnl">first</div>
<div class="panel" id="MainContent_Panel1">second</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function showPanel(panId)
    {
      var getAllPanels = document.getElementsByClassName("panels"); /*get All element having class panels*/
      for(var i=0; i<getAllPanels.length;i++)
      {
        if(getAllPanels.item(i).id=='panId')
        {
          getAllPanels.item(i).style.display='block';
        }else{
          getAllPanels.item(i).style.display='none'; 
        }
     }

    }
```

```
      <ul class="pager">
        <li class="previous panels" id='pnl' onclick="showPanel('pnl')"><a href="#">Today's Action Items</a> </li>
         <li class="next panels" id='Panel1' onclick="showPanel('Panel1')"><a href="#" >All Pending Action Items</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Edited because you may have use jquery library for $.each loop i placed earlier
Now with javascript for loop will work for you :)